# Gimme this join or that join (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, join

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as snitch_count 
FROM snitchings 
JOIN pimps ON pimps.pimp_id=snitchings.pimp_id 
JOIN prostitutes ON prostitutes.prostitute_id=snitchings.prostitute_id 
WHERE snitchings.case_id=4538;
```

This is what I have and it runs but it doesn't seem right (the tables exist but there's no test/dummy data yet so I can't fully know). I believe the above query will return the total sum of snitchings for pimps AND prostitutes, as a pair, for that given case (they're huge cases). But I need the query to return the total sum of snitchings for pimps OR prostitutes. How do I fix that query to do this?

DISCLAIMER: I'm probably exhausted from coding for hours on end, please excuse me if my syntax or explanation is a little wonky

Comment: Apparently pimps now require a way to handle their prostitutes....

Comment: ...or the ADA needs to track how many people they need to give clothes vouchers to so they look presentable in court

Comment: All jokes aside, I simply changed the table names and columns to those in the OP to protect my app. I do need help getting this to work though

Comment: maybe make it a simple or contrived example? pimps, snitches, and prostitutes is definitely not an appropriate contrived example

Comment: I figured since there's so many police and crime shows on TV pimps, snitches and prostitutes was the easiest analogy to my setup. Its definitely not simple and the given example fits it like a glove

Comment: You need to change the names of your tables and columns to "protect" your app? I think you are doing it wrong, or your app is word press. Or both

Comment: P.S. The title should have been: "Gimme this join or I'll slap you".

Answer (score 1):

No, your query will find lines in snitchings that have a valid `pimp_id` AND a valid `prostitute_id`.

Are you sure you need a JOIN? Can table `snitchings` have invalid values in `prostitute_id` or `pimp_id`? Else, this would work:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as snitch_count 
FROM snitchings 
WHERE snitches.prostitute_id IS NOT NULL OR snitches.pimp_id IS NOT NULL
```

If you do need a join, and both are exclusive, (either a snitch is a prostitute OR a pimp), this should work:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as snitch_count 
FROM snitchings 
LEFT JOIN pimps ON pimps.pimp_id=snitches.pimp_id 
LEFT JOIN prostitutes ON prostitutes.prostitute_id=snitches.prostitute_id 
WHERE snitchings.case_id=4538 AND 
(pimps.pimp_id IS NOT NULL OR prostitutes.prostitute_id IS NOT NULL)
```

Else, you need to count them seperately (but you could UNION and SUM if you really want to:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as snitch_count 
FROM snitchings 
JOIN pimps ON pimps.pimp_id=snitches.pimp_id 
WHERE snitchings.case_id=4538;

SELECT COUNT(*) as snitch_count 
FROM snitchings 
JOIN prostitutes ON prostitutes.prostitute_id=snitches.prostitute_id 
WHERE snitchings.case_id=4538;
```

Comment: Hmmm... looks like both the second to last or last query should do the trick. If I do use UNION and SUM, which query is faster and more efficient?